# ¿Cómo leer una porción específica de un archivo txt en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, archivo, bucle-for

**Necesito extraer una porción de texto de un archivo txt.**
El archivo es así:

```
STARTINGWORKIN DD/MM/AAAA HH:MM:SS<br/>
...lineas de texto...<br/>
...más lineas de texto...<br/>
STARTINGWORKING DD/MM/AAAA HH:MM:SS<br/>
...lineas de texto que quiero...<br/>
...lineas de texto que quiero...
```

*-El archivo empieza con `startingwork` y termina en lineas de texto.*
**Necesito extraer la porción de texto final después del último STARTINGWORK**

```py
    archivo="registros.txt"
    if archivo.endswith(".txt"):
      if os.path.exists(archivo):
        lineas=[linea.rstrip('\n') for linea in open(archivo)]
        for linea in lineas:
            #extraer la porción
```

Comment: revisé el ejemplo mínimo, pueden aclarar el problema? este mismo post lo hice en stackoverflow en inglés y no hubo ningún problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes tener una variable que guarde todas las líneas que has leido desde el último `STARTINGWORK`. Al terminar de procesar el fichero tendrás justamente lo que necesitabas.

Por cierto que no necesitas leer primero todas las líneas a una lista. Puedes iterar directamente sobre el fichero abierto y eso te devuelve una línea de cada vez. Es decir:

```
resultado = []
with open(archivo) as f:
    for linea in f:
        if linea.startswith("STARTINGWORK"):
            resultado = []       # Borrar lo que hubiera acumulado
        resultado.append(linea)  # Añadir la última línea leida

# En resultado tienes todo lo que hay tras el último STARTINGWORK, inclusive
# Puedes quedarte con resultado[1:] si quieres eliminar el STARTINGWORK inicial
print("".join(resultado))
```

Esta solución no funciona bien si la cadena "STARTINGWORK" no aparece al principio de ninguna línea, pues en ese caso `resultado` contendría todas las líneas del fichero.

Comment: Funcionó!!! Lo único que me queda es sacar de resultado la línea STARTINGWORK

Answer (score 1):

Benja,

Se me ocurre que para evitar recorrer todo el file, lo leas de abajo para arriba, guardes todo hasta que encuentres la primera (la última) línea con el texto que buscas.

Para leer en reversa, encontré [otra pregunta en SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26747854/11649862)
Sería algo así: Primero, el código para leer en reversa

```
import os

def readlines_reverse(filename):
    with open(filename) as qfile:
        qfile.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
        position = qfile.tell()
        line = ''
        while position >= 0:
            qfile.seek(position)
            next_char = qfile.read(1)
            if next_char == "\n":
                yield line[::-1]
                line = ''
            else:
                line += next_char
            position -= 1
        yield line[::-1]
```

Y luego el que sería para la lectura:

```
archivo = 'input.txt'

for linea in readlines_reverse(archivo):
    print(linea) #aqui haces lo que quieras con la linea
    if 'startingwork' in linea:
        break
```

Lo único malo es que estaría todo en el orden contrario. Lo puedes cambiar con el mismo método, o bien poniendo cada línea en una lista y luego revertir esa lista.

```
l = []
for linea in readlines_reverse(archivo):
    l.append(linea)
    if 'startingwork' in linea:
        break

l.reverse()
print(l)
```

Si no quieres tener la linea startingwork incluida, puedes poner un `else` debajo del `if` y mover el `print(linea)` ahí.

Lo probé con un archivo grande (1.11 GiB) y funciona rápido :D

Comment: Hola, esté funciona excelente, pero comparado con la respuesta seleccionada, tiene más lineas de código. Pero funciona de todas maneras :)

Comment: Claro, pero para aclarar, esta alternativa la hice teniendo en cuenta archivos pesados (más de 500 MiBs), donde quizás no sea óptimo recorrer todo el archivo cada vez que lo ejecutes. Saludos!